# Highcharts Bug: Chart out of boundary

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I'm using highcharts 4.2.1, and when I zoom in, the chart will be out of boundary horizontally.

Does anyone have some ideas?

[image]

Comment: Please add code snippet and chart type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you've somewhere in your series configuration, the `clip` parameter set equal to `false`, that's why the problem occurs. Please set it to `true` on all series in your chart by this code:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    clip: true
  }
}
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/syhamc8u/

Comment: Thanks so much! It actually works! Sorry I don't have much "reputation" to click a thumb up though.